# Sort by all columns in table pure angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to give a table the ability to sort by all columns, but having a bit of trouble. I am pulling some data from a webservice to populate the table but then want to sort wherever the user wants. I have a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZpppaqdYOlqkHvf2fbnL?p=preview). Of my close attempt. I was thinking something like this:

```
$scope.order = function(predicate, reverse) {
      $scope.recentalerts = orderBy($scope.recentalerts, predicate, reverse);
    };
```

like from the angular website might work, but am having a bit of trouble integrating it into my own table. What am I doing wrong? Or is there an easier way to do so? I'd like to just stick with plain angular like [this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

Comment: Plunkr doesn't work, angular seem to be not found, could you fix that?

Comment: Yeah, shoot sorry about that. 1 moment

Comment: I honestly dont know why it isnt working on plunker, I was just thinking it was an error with the ordering. The data shows up on my webapplication

Comment: missing dependencies in plunker and path wrong to scripts.js

Comment: Okay, dependencies sorted out. Now It just the trouble I am having with sorting

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/zik9MdoYolpQcbkw6Ep1?p=preview your example fixed, plz watch console errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is working (after fixing the plunkR), however you always force `reverse` to `false`.

If you want to reproduce what Angular do, which is inverse the `reverse` parameter on each click, you could for instance add somehting like this:

```
$scope.orders[predicate] = !$scope.orders[predicate];
$scope.recentalerts = orderBy($scope.recentalerts, predicate, $scope.orders[predicate]);
```

See working plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z9LDlWvwWV82D65pfiF6?p=preview

Or in a simpler form, use a common `$scope.reverse` attribute:

http://plnkr.co/edit/sMD7ZqmsJ7bULa26jo6q?p=preview

Comment: +1 for the preserving of ordering for each column, that always irritated me and I could never find out a good way to do it, I guess I needed some more coffee when I tried to do it because this is simple and awesome.

Comment: The `$scope.reverse` is killer. Thanks for pointing that out. Also (why was plunker broken?) It was working on my webapp. Sometimes plunker is funky and idk why?

Comment: You forgot `$http` in the dependencies of your controller: `['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $http, $filter)`. Always open your developper console to check for any errors when you do development, including is plunkr, that will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of what I use for rolling my own sorting in tables. Simply using a string to determine what property I want to sort by (with reverse supported) and changing it dynamically, then using orderBy on the ng-repeat.

Hope this helps.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.sortBy = 'ID';
      $scope.sort = function(sortBy) {
        if ($scope.sortBy == sortBy) {
          $scope.sortBy = '-' + sortBy
        } else {
          $scope.sortBy = sortBy;
        }
      }

      $scope.people = [{
        'ID': 1,
        'Name': 'Aaron',
        'Age': 70
      }, {
        'ID': 28,
        'Name': 'Ben',
        'Age': 60
      }, {
        'ID': 2,
        'Name': 'Claire',
        'Age': 50
      }, {
        'ID': 14,
        'Name': 'Damian',
        'Age': 40
      }, {
        'ID': 8,
        'Name': 'Frank',
        'Age': 30
      }];
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div style="margin: 1em">
        <h4>Recent Alerts</h4>
        <div>
          <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th ng-click="sort('ID')">ID
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" ng-show="sortBy=='-ID'"></i>
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-up" ng-show="sortBy=='ID'"></i>
                </th>
                <th ng-click="sort('Name')">Name
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" ng-show="sortBy=='-Name'"></i>
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-up" ng-show="sortBy=='Name'"></i>
                </th>
                <th ng-click="sort('Age')">Age
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" ng-show="sortBy=='-Age'"></i>
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-up" ng-show="sortBy=='Age'"></i>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr data-ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy: sortBy">
                <td ng-bind="person.ID"></td>
                <td ng-bind="person.Name"></td>
                <td ng-bind="person.Age"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```